# Can I say 'I've splurged on another lipstick, provided that I have a bunch of them?'

Tags: british-english

Can 'provided that' be used here? Is it okay?

Comment: What do you think that 'provided that' should mean in this context?

Comment: like 'I have a lot of stuff like that so why I buy another one'

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELU. This site encourages users to show what they have found in the research they did to find an answer to their question. Have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to better understand how to edit your question.

Comment: "provided that" usually means something like "on condition that," and it only refers to things happening in the future. So "I will splurge on another lipstick provided that I get the money for it tomorrow" makes sense, but "I did something (in the past) provided that [something that is already true]" makes no sense.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/provided-that

Comment: If you have applied more lipstick, then you already had some. You can express something conditionally in the past, for example as: "I *would have* splurged on more lipstick *if* I'd had some." But you **didn't** do it.

Comment: "provided that" doesn't work for something that happened in the past. So, the sentence doesn't make sense. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

"provided that" usually means something like "on condition that," and it only refers to things happening in the future. So "I will splurge on another lipstick provided that I get the money for it tomorrow" makes sense, but "I did something (in the past) provided that [something that is already true]" makes no sense. –  See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/provided-that

The word "splurge" is a very casual way of saying "spend too much money", and "a bunch of lipsticks" is also pretty casual.  But you could say "I splurged on more lipstick, although I already have a bunch of them".